# C++: incompatible types in assignment of

Tags: c++, struct

I create this `struct`:

```
struct message_text{
                    char text[1024];
};

message_text instance;

instance.text = "HELLO WORLD, FIRST MESSAGE";
```

I get this error:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘const char [27]’ to ‘char [1024]’
         instance.text = "HELLO WORLD, FIRST MESSAGE";
```

I don't understand this error because the size of `instance.text` does not exceed the maximum message size, which is 1024 bytes.

I have seen other similar questions but I could not understand what my mistake was when creating the structure

Help is appreciated

Comment: You would not have this problem with std::string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others mentioned, you should be using `std::string`. But if you really want to assign a string literal to the array, you can do like below:

```
struct message_text{
        char text[1024];
        template <int N>
        void assignText(const char (&other)[N]) {
            static_assert(N < 1024, "String contains more than 1024 chars");
            for(int i =0 ; i < N ; ++i) {
                text[i] = other[i];
            }
        }
};
```

Note:

1. The above only works for assigning from string literals or char arrays. Does not support null terminated strings.
2. Since `assignText` is a template, it generates a function for each usage with unique N. This might lead to increased binary size.
3. Since `assignText` is a template, you have to define it in a header or within the same source file.

Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/g/1oLcAq

Answer (score 1):

`char` arrays don't work like that - you can't assign them in the same way you would an `int`, for example (although you can do it when initializing the array). If you want to copy that literal into your `char` array, use `strncpy`.

Or, better than that, seeing as you've tagged it as C++ - just use the standard `string` class.

Comment: Worth an edit to point out that you can initialize a character array by doing  what Asker did, but you cannot assign.

Comment: It very rarely makes sense to use `strncpy`, which in spite of the name is not a "safer" `strcpy`. [I've written about this.](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: and just to anticipate the next question -  use std::vector instead of arrays

Comment: `strncpy` is a poor choice as it does not null-terminate the output sometimes